# Displaying Specific Lines From a Text File on Console - Batch Files

Tags: batch-file

Okay So I have a text document displaying various logs. An example of one of these logs is as follows:

```
Session Begin: 11/04/2013 -  1:36:52.87 
10002,CREATE,100 
LIST 
10002,DEPOSIT,100 
10002,DEPOSIT,250 
10002,DEPOSIT,150 
Session END: 11/04/2013 -  1:37:23.95
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is displaying all the lines that have '10002' in them onto the console. There are more numbers (or in my case account numbers) and theyre all set to a variable %AccNum%. Simplicity would also be helpful here, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
find "10002" yourlogfile.txt
```

would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: Holy Crap, I must have been over-thinking the hell out of this one, Thanks So Much! :)